# How to disable NTLM authentication in IISnode apps?

Tags: node.js, iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, iisnode

We are deploying a NodeJS application to production via IISnode. Every time a user tries to log in, they are greeted with a additional login prompt after logging in to the app, which always lead to a nice 401 access denied error.

The response headers for this page are as follows:

```
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate:Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate:NTLM
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Clearly there's some additional windows/iis authentication mechanism, preventing our users from accessing the application. How can I disable this?